# Is there a way to change tailwind default style option?

Tags: html, css, next.js, html-lists, tailwind-css

I'm building a blog in NextJS. Apparently in Tailwind's [list style type](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type) the default style is `list-none`. So every `<ul> <li>` elements in my app is not styled at all.

I use [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs) to process `.md` files and my function returns `<ul> <li>` without classes so in this case I can't specify the classes by manually writing them.

- Is there any way to change this default styling so my `<ul> <li>` is not plain text?
- or is there any way to give a `list-disc` class to all `<ul> <li>`?
- or is there any way to exclude certain `<div>`s from being styled by Tailwind?
- other approach?

I tried this

```
// tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
      // ...
     listStyleType: false,
    }
  }
```

but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Directives

You can use a [preprocessor](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-post-css-as-your-preprocessor) like [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) you can use the [@apply](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply)  or use the [@layer](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer) directive.

```css
ul {
 @apply list-disc;
}

OR

@tailwind base;
@layer base{
 ul {
  @apply list-disc;
 }
}
```

---

##### Base styles

You can also use [base styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles#using-css)

// tailwind.config.js

```css
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addBase, theme }) {
      addBase({
        'ul': { listStyle: 'disc' },
      })
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Object key can't use short line. list-style must be listStyle.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the tailwind default nomalized stylings ([preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight)) from the tailwind.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to my stylesheet, which seems to solve it:

```
@layer base {
   ul, ol {
      list-style: revert-layer;
   }
}
```

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=revert-layer) support is almost non-existent. But I tested this in recent versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Edge on Mac and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the tailwind plugin `@tailwindcss/typography`: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin

Use `prose` class to wrap your markdown content, so that tailwind default style would be removed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).